# Insert null values into date column

Tags: doctrine-orm

How do I insert/update null values in date columns in Doctrine2?

I've set the date column to nullable=true.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateBar;
```

And I've tried this:

```
$foo->setDateBar(new \DateTime()); // Inserts today's date
$foo->setDateBar();  // Throws error
```

I couldn't find anything in the doctrine2's documentation either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that your setDateBar always expects a parameter?  Try:

```
public function setDateBar($date = null)
{
    $this->dateBar = $date;
}
```

If that is not the problem then please post your error message.